# T-SQL clause where with datepart from field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, datepart

I need to write something like that:

```
select a, b, c 
from table
where dateadd(a, b, c) < getdate()
```

With:

```
a=nvarchar: YY, D, ...
b=int
c=date
```

for "b" and "c" there are no problems, but the datepart can't be a field, only static type: just YY, YYYY, D, ....

How could I solve it?

In reality the problem is another but this system seemed easier to solve.

The original problem is this, maybe you can solve it in another way: I have rows of a table that remain valid for a duration called X.

If this duration X is defined in days, there are problems with leap years (eg 365 days is different from 1 year). if I express it in years (eg 1 year) or months, the datepart function helps me: dateadd (YY, 1, dateFrom) is perfect.

So I thought not to use the field "validity duration" expressed in days but using two fields, one for the value and one for the type (months, years, weeks).

Only that datepart does not allow it.

Comment: resolved by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by myself.

```
 where
      CASE [a]  
         WHEN 'YY' THEN dateadd(YY,[b],[c])
         WHEN 'DD' THEN dateadd(DD,[b],[c])
...
      END
```

Not elegant, but it works.